# WMI: Win32_ScheduledJob: How do I set UntilTime?

Tags: c#, windows, scripting, wmi

Win32_ScheduledJob: How do I set UntilTime?

I am worried that the process will end abruptly after 72 hours due to the scheduled task default setting:
"Stop the task if it runs for [  72 ] hour(s)"

Will the task actually end after 72 hours?

I can set UntilTime but it has no effect on the scheduled task.

For example C#:

```
System.Management.ManagementClass classInstance;
...
string strTime = "********" + String.Format("{0:HHmmss}", dtSchdTask) + ".000000+000";
object[] arrParams = {"\""+ sProc + "\"", strTime, false, null, null, true, mjob };
...
DateTime dtUntilTime = DateTime.MaxValue;
string strUntilTime = String.Format("{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}", dtUntilTime)  + ".000000+000";
classInstance.SetPropertyValue("UntilTime", strUntilTime);
...
classInstance.InvokeMethod("Create", arrParams);
```